# Base-64 to Mat conversion opencv

Tags: java, c++, opencv, base64, javacv

How can I convert base-64 string to Mat format in opencv.

I need to send a image from jave to C++ ( opencv Code ).

How to do this in C++ uisng opencv? or in C++?

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you. Do you have a string containing pixel values which you then need to convert to a cv::Mat?

Comment: @Rasmus In java am converting a Bitmap to Byte-array. Then I am converting this Byte-array to base-64 and sending it to C++. Now in C++ dll I need to convert this base-64 string to Mat. Hope this will be clear now?

Answer (score 1):

It's an absolute mystery to me why you go Base64 in the first place (do you want to transmit your picture through Morse code?) but for sure you have to first convert your string into propper bytes again before you can convert it into cv::Mat. So you have to use whatever function and caracter set you used to generate the Base64 string to unfold it again. As soon as you have a proper byte array its quite easy to get a cv::Mat :

```
cv::Mat image(height,rows,CV_8UC3,array.data());
```

If you do not intend to transmit your image through ancient communication systems, I would take this shortcut and directly read in the bitmap:

```
Mat image;
image = imread("full/path/of/image.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

And would also recommend that you do everything in C++ or use javaCV. I hope this was helpful - I am not sure whether I got what you want to do.